# Node.js ''Skips'' a line of code?? [screenshot]

Tags: node.js, bots

i am making a script that will take a picture of my desktop (for server disk stuff) but it doesn't take the picture. But it will when i create another script and run that.

```
const screenshot = require('screenshot-desktop')
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === '!Photo') {
    
    screenshot({ filename: 'C:/Users/MyName/Desktop/TestPictureFile.png' })
    Bot.sendFile(`C:/Users/MyName/Desktop/TestPictureFile.png`);
  }
});
```

If i only put `screenshot({ filename: 'C:/Users/MyName/Desktop/TestPictureFile.png' })` In another script, it works fine. But it doesn't when i try the code above this one.

Comment: Is `screenshot()` asynchronous?

Comment: Also, how do you determine it doesn't work? Did you check the directory? Did you try debugging/logging?

Comment: According to [the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/screenshot-desktophttps://www.npmjs.com/package/screenshot-desktop) `screenshot-desktop` is indeed async. You'll need to `await` it or move `Bot.sendFile` into a `then` block depending on your setup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever a function writes/reads a file (or query database) it is most likely asynchronous which means you need to wait for it to write/read the file then continue.

As you can see in the docs https://www.npmjs.com/package/screenshot-desktop#usage

`screenshot()` returns a Promise so you have 2 options.

First, call `Bot.sendFile` in the `then` function like so

```
client.on('message', msg => {
    if (msg.content === '!Photo') {    
        screenshot({ filename: 'C:/Users/MyName/Desktop/TestPictureFile.png' }).then(function(){
            Bot.sendFile(`C:/Users/MyName/Desktop/TestPictureFile.png`);
        })
    }
});
```

or use `await` like so

```
client.on('message', msg => {
    if (msg.content === '!Photo') {    
        await screenshot({ filename: 'C:/Users/MyName/Desktop/TestPictureFile.png' })
        Bot.sendFile(`C:/Users/MyName/Desktop/TestPictureFile.png`);
    }
});
```